# Broke my terminal while installing MongoDB

Tags: html, bash, terminal

I was working on installing MongoDB and following some steps I found online. Somehow I broke the terminal because every time I load my terminal I get:

```
-bash: uname: command not found
-bash: ps: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: dirname: command not found
-bash: brew: command not found
```

Also tried to go back into VIM to fix a path and I get

`bash: vim: command not found`

Any way to reset the terminal to fix this?

My view: [Terminal Window](https://ibb.co/7GC8kH9)

Comment: I'm guessing it has to do with the path but I'm not sure how to get there or reset it

Comment: Start with `echo $PATH`;  `echo` is a builtin command, run directly by `bash`.

Comment: @phd I have no idea what that means

Answer (score -1):

Run this to get a sane `PATH` again:

```
 export PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)
```

If they exist, you may want to source these files:

```
 cd
 . ./.profile
 . ./.bashrc
```

Comment: This works... but when terminal is closed I get the same error :(

Comment: @Brenner Then it looks like you deleted your shell profile. Try to salvage with `echo 'export PATH=$(/usr/bin/getconf PATH)' > .bashrc`.